# Docker network_mode: host connect to 10.x.x.x ip outside

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with connection to db; unfortunately I can change anything only for docker, I cant change any of ip on server.

I have a server, it have mysql server(localhost - 127.0.0.1) and mysql server from hosting (10.253.x.x). Access to localhost works fine when I use network_mode host but with 10.x I got Can't connect to server on '10.253.x.x'.

my docker-compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
    admin_web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        container_name: admin_web
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./../../:/var/www
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        network_mode: host
```

How I can connect to second db? Maybe some ip mapping or something.

Comment: You’re missing port expose in your Docker compose. Eg. 5555:3306 will allow the outside to reach this container’s MySQL service using the 5555 port.

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-network-mode-host-connect-to-10-x-x-x-ip-outside/119166

Comment: @emix this is about reaching out from the container, to a 10.x address which is reachable alright from the host perspective. as applications running inside containers normally are not restricted accessing IP services like http, there must be something special about the 10.x range here. I have a very similar problem: got a 10.1.1.x address for an smtp gateway, can send from the host, cannot send from within the container (timeout on port 25) while the container can communicate with identity services (443) using a domain name just fine.